# Server-side time format differs from client-side

Tags: bug, status-completed, timestamps

I have found two pages where the server-side time format does not match the format that is used by the auto-update script on client-side. In particular when the page is loaded the time displays as `42m` first and after a minute it gets updated to `43 mins`.

This one is from the [newest posts list in the profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware?tab=profile#top-posts):

<sub>Left side when page loaded; Right side a minute later:</sub>

[image]

The other one I found was the [recently awarded badges list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6/supporter):

<sub>Left side when page loaded; Right side a minute later:</sub>

[image]

As you can see, the *minutes* and *hours* (and probably *seconds* too) are abbreviated differently.

Comment: We need to bring back Jeff just so he can go hit you with a giant Abbr. ;)

Comment: Gosh, I looked at it as "Is he complaining about that there's one more minute shown when a minute has passed? O.o" :D Needed 5 minutes to figure out that you were talking about the "m"/" mins" thing :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made the first load time format more consistent with the JS updated one.

Fixed and being deployed.

Comment: But now the time does not dynamically update anymore. They had a `class="relativetime"` before that's missing now.

Comment: Whoops. Looking at fixing that.